# Cannot Connect to FTP Server in Whonix

Tags: networking, ftp, tor

I'm trying to connect to an FTP server using Filezilla from within Whonix (Windows 10 host OS), but I'm getting the following error after successfully logging in:

```
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PORT 10,152,152,11,140,201
Response:   200 PORT command successful
Command:    MLSD
Response:   425 Unable to build data connection: Connection refused
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I get that error when I use an active connection. When I use a passive connection, it times out. If I increase the time limit, it gets stuck at "retrieving directory listing." I am using "only use plain FTP (insecure)" because that is the only kind the server supports.

It's worth noting that I have been able to successfully connect to another FTP server from within Whonix. It just seems like I'm having trouble with this particular one, so I'm not really sure what to do. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It's a firewall or NAT issue. – To the other FTP server, can you connect with the active or the passive mode?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The other one was using an active connection.

Comment: See my article about [network configuration needed for FTP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).